# WittyPi on Pi Zero W - I2C read / write fail

Tags: gpio, raspbian-stretch, i2c, pi-zero-w, rtc

I've connected WittyPi2 (an RTC Power Management hat) to my Pi Zero W - but I'm constantly getting failures in the log, to do with the I2C communication:

```
I2C read 0x01 0x68 0x09 failed (result=), and no more retry
I2C write 0x01 0x68 0x09 21 failed (result=), and no more retry
```

WittyPi2 runs schedules to start-up and shutdown the Pi at set intervals. The Pi can do one round of shutdown/start-up, but after this point the I2C errors begin. The Pi is running Raspbian Stretch, flashed.

The Pi was bought with pre-soldered headers, and the GPIO pins are all responding how they should - so I don't believe it's a physical problem. I've also tried this on a number of Zero Ws now with the same result. However, this works absolutely fine on my 3B.

Running 'i2cdetect -y 1' in the terminal shows 'UU' in the 68 channel.

I've tried playing around with different things in the /boot/config.txt file (e.g. dtparam=i2c_arm=on), including, as per WittyPi suggestions for the Pi 3, 'enable_uart=1'. I'm still getting I2C read and write errors.

If anybody has any suggestions at all, I'd be very very very grateful! :-)

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Why are you trying to write directly to the I2C device when a kernel driver owns it. Use the kernel interface to write to it. (Note: I'm assuming 0x68 is a RTC, `sudo hwclock` with various operands should read or write t it.)

Comment: I have had problems with RPZ as well, not only bad conections, but 2 RPzw DIED after using wittypiMini. I am not sure if the vendor has tested it properly using Rpzw, because I have been in trouble for many many times, and the same unit that burned my rpzw worked fine on Rpi3.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> 1. WittyPi2 on Pi Zero W Raspbian Stretch - I2C read / write fail
> 2. The Pi can do one round of shutdown/start-up, but after this point the I2C errors begin.
> 3. However, this works absolutely fine on my 3B.

***Answer***

Well, if WittyPi2 works well with Rpi3B but not RpiZero stretch, then the problem is with RpiZero.

> The WittyPi2 user guide says their software is tested with ***jessie***.  If
>   your Rpi3 uses jessie, but RpiZerp uses ***stretch***, then it is likely
>   that the software is ***not compatible*** with stretch.

One more thing is that the user guide says i2cdetect -y 1 should detect RTC DS3231 address of 0x68 (or also 0x57).  If you see UU, then it is likely that you have some DT overlay thing confusing Raspbian.

[image: wittypi2]

***References***

[Witty Pi 2 RTC & Power Management for Raspberry Pi Boards - UUGear CAD $32](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/witty-pi-2-rtc--power-management-raspberry-pi-boards.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwla7nBRDxARIsADll0kDB8CazShlv-K3MLWollyHuN0sJwpIlv2nB6cb2O7fUvKfKvDKRaKUaAoHKEALw_wcB)

[WITTY PI 2 - CZK480](http://www.uugear.com/product/wittypi2/)

[WittyPi2 User Manual](http://www.uugear.com/doc/WittyPi2_UserManual.pdf)

> The software of Witty Pi 2 has been tested under Raspbian Jessie.
>   Raspbian Wheezy should also work, but it is better to use Jessie as it
>   will be much easier to install Qt 5, which is required by the
>   (optional) GUI of the software.
>
> If you have installed the OS with NOOBS, please make sure to skip the
>   boot menu. Otherwise the boot menu will postpone the booting long
>   enough to make Witty Pi 2 think the system is down and then cut the
>   power (so your Raspberry Pi will not boot).
>
> Please notice that sudo is necessary to run this script. This script
>   will automatically do these tasks in sequence:
>
> 1. Enable I2C on your Raspberry Pi
> 2. Install i2c-tools, if it is not installed yet
> 3. Configure Bluetooth to use mini-UART (Raspberry Pi 3 only)
> 4. Install wiringPi, if it is not installed yet
> 5. Install Witty Pi programs, if they are not installed yet
> 6. Remove fake-hwclock and disable ntpd daemon
> 7. Install Qt 5, if it is not installed yet (it is optional, and is for Jessie only) The fake-hwclock package is no longer needed as you
>      have a real hardware clock now. Removing fake-hwclock package can
>      avoid some potential problems (e.g. this one). Also the ntpd daemon
>      should be disabled to avoid corrupting the RTC time. Disabling ntpd
>      will not affect the NTP (Network Time Protocol) time synchronization
>      as Witty Pi software will explicitly query NTP time and then update to
>      system and RTC.
>
> The Qt 5 installation is for the GUI only. If you don?t plan to use
>   it, you can skip this step for now, as Qt 5 installation will take a
>   while.
>
> You will then see a new “wittyPi” directory, and it contains 5
>   runnable files… viz.:
>
> Software Update/Uninstallation
>
> If you want to update the software to newer version, you don?t have to
>   uninstall it first. Just remove or rename your “wittyPi” directory and
>   repeat the installing process, then you are all set.